# Polka dots shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, texturing, materials, shaders

For a project i need to texture an irregular shaped object with equally spaced black dots and also with dots of different sizes, locations. The way it must be done is by the intersection of spheres with the object surface. I have tried shading with OSL, but a need to choose actual surface points to serves as pivots for the spheres which as far as i know OSL doesn't provide. Is there any other method for doing this? The texture must be displayed correctly, so no UV mapping since the objects are quite complex.

Thanks.

Comment: will the object be animated?

Answer (score 10):

Provided you are after random dots, i.e. the dots don't need to be arranged in any particular fashion, then the built in Voronoi texture works well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. For this project however more control is needed since the texture should be noisy as well as regular and i should be able to change the shape of the dots for example to ellipses. This is for a psychophysics experiment.

Comment: @user14641 You could use the mapping node to stretch the texture, making the "spheres" into oblong oval shapes which look like ellipses when intersected with the object's surface.